# Query in a class with variable

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I have created a timeclock system for a website admin area I am working on. But I want to use a class to handle the code in a better way so I am starting over. So far I have 2 classes. One to handle the database connection and the queries to the database through PDO.

When starting the class for the timeclock (Which I am having to build from scratch) I am getting close because I am no longer receiving errors when I load the page. But the results of the query are not right as I should be returning "true" instead of NULL for a record coming from the database. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

**My Database class is like so(From GitHub)...**

```
/**
 *  DB - A simple database class 
 *
 * @author      Author: Vivek Wicky Aswal. (https://twitter.com/#!/VivekWickyAswal)
 * @git         https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class
 * @version      0.2ab
 *
 */
require("Log.class.php");
class DB
{
    # @object, The PDO object
    private $pdo;

    # @object, PDO statement object
    private $sQuery;

    # @array,  The database settings
    private $settings;

    # @bool ,  Connected to the database
    private $bConnected = false;

    # @object, Object for logging exceptions    
    private $log;

    # @array, The parameters of the SQL query
    private $parameters;

       /**
    *   Default Constructor 
    *
    *   1. Instantiate Log class.
    *   2. Connect to database.
    *   3. Creates the parameter array.
    */
        public function __construct()
        {           
            $this->log = new Log(); 
            $this->Connect();
            $this->parameters = array();
        }

       /**
    *   This method makes connection to the database.
    *   
    *   1. Reads the database settings from a ini file. 
    *   2. Puts  the ini content into the settings array.
    *   3. Tries to connect to the database.
    *   4. If connection failed, exception is displayed and a log file gets created.
    */
        private function Connect()
        {
                        $host = 'localhost';
                        $username = 'root';
                        $password = '';
                        $dbname = 'acro_1986';
            //$this->settings = parse_ini_file("settings.ini.php");
            $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$host.'';
            try 
            {
                # Read settings from INI file, set UTF8
                $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

                # We can now log any exceptions on Fatal error. 
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                # Disable emulation of prepared statements, use REAL prepared statements instead.
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

                # Connection succeeded, set the boolean to true.
                $this->bConnected = true;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) 
            {
                # Write into log
                echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage());
                die();
            }
        }
    /*
     *   You can use this little method if you want to close the PDO connection
     *
     */
        public function CloseConnection()
        {
            # Set the PDO object to null to close the connection
            # http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
            $this->pdo = null;
        }

       /**
    *   Every method which needs to execute a SQL query uses this method.
    *   
    *   1. If not connected, connect to the database.
    *   2. Prepare Query.
    *   3. Parameterize Query.
    *   4. Execute Query.   
    *   5. On exception : Write Exception into the log + SQL query.
    *   6. Reset the Parameters.
    */  
        private function Init($query,$parameters = "")
        {
        # Connect to database
        if(!$this->bConnected) { $this->Connect(); }
        try {
                # Prepare query
                $this->sQuery = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

                # Add parameters to the parameter array 
                $this->bindMore($parameters);

                # Bind parameters
                if(!empty($this->parameters)) {
                    foreach($this->parameters as $param)
                    {
                        $parameters = explode("\x7F",$param);
                        $this->sQuery->bindParam($parameters[0],$parameters[1]);
                    }       
                }

                # Execute SQL 
                $this->succes   = $this->sQuery->execute();     
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                    # Write into log and display Exception
                    echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage(), $query );
                    die();
            }

            # Reset the parameters
            $this->parameters = array();
        }

       /**
    *   @void 
    *
    *   Add the parameter to the parameter array
    *   @param string $para  
    *   @param string $value 
    */  
        public function bind($para, $value)
        {   
            $this->parameters[sizeof($this->parameters)] = ":" . $para . "\x7F" . utf8_encode($value);
        }
       /**
    *   @void
    *   
    *   Add more parameters to the parameter array
    *   @param array $parray
    */  
        public function bindMore($parray)
        {
            if(empty($this->parameters) && is_array($parray)) {
                $columns = array_keys($parray);
                foreach($columns as $i => &$column) {
                    $this->bind($column, $parray[$column]);
                }
            }
        }
       /**
    *       If the SQL query  contains a SELECT or SHOW statement it returns an array containing all of the result set row
    *   If the SQL statement is a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement it returns the number of affected rows
    *
    *       @param  string $query
    *   @param  array  $params
    *   @param  int    $fetchmode
    *   @return mixed
    */          
        public function query($query,$params = null, $fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
        {
            $query = trim($query);

            $this->Init($query,$params);

            $rawStatement = explode(" ", $query);

            # Which SQL statement is used 
            $statement = strtolower($rawStatement[0]);

            if ($statement === 'select' || $statement === 'show') {
                return $this->sQuery->fetchAll($fetchmode);
            }
            elseif ( $statement === 'insert' ||  $statement === 'update' || $statement === 'delete' ) {
                return $this->sQuery->rowCount();   
            }   
            else {
                return NULL;
            }
        }

      /**
       *  Returns the last inserted id.
       *  @return string
       */   
        public function lastInsertId() {
            return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
        }   

       /**
    *   Returns an array which represents a column from the result set 
    *
    *   @param  string $query
    *   @param  array  $params
    *   @return array
    */  
        public function column($query,$params = null)
        {
            $this->Init($query,$params);
            $Columns = $this->sQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);     

            $column = null;

            foreach($Columns as $cells) {
                $column[] = $cells[0];
            }

            return $column;

        }   
       /**
    *   Returns an array which represents a row from the result set 
    *
    *   @param  string $query
    *   @param  array  $params
    *       @param  int    $fetchmode
    *   @return array
    */  
        public function row($query,$params = null,$fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
        {               
            $this->Init($query,$params);
            return $this->sQuery->fetch($fetchmode);            
        }
       /**
    *   Returns the value of one single field/column
    *
    *   @param  string $query
    *   @param  array  $params
    *   @return string
    */  
        public function single($query,$params = null)
        {
            $this->Init($query,$params);
            return $this->sQuery->fetchColumn();
        }
       /**  
    * Writes the log and returns the exception
    *
    * @param  string $message
    * @param  string $sql
    * @return string
    */
    private function ExceptionLog($message , $sql = "")
    {
        $exception  = 'Unhandled Exception. <br />';
        $exception .= $message;
        $exception .= "<br /> You can find the error back in the log.";

        if(!empty($sql)) {
            # Add the Raw SQL to the Log
            $message .= "\r\nRaw SQL : "  . $sql;
        }
            # Write into log
            $this->log->write($message);

        return $exception;
    }

}
```

**My Timeclock class...**

```
class Timeclock {
    public $user_id;
    public function __construct($user_id) {
        $this->user_id = $user_id ;
        $this->db = new Db();
        //$this->clocked_in = is_user_clocked_in($user_id);
    }
    public function is_user_clocked_in(){
        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM timeclock WHERE user_id = :user_id AND time_out IS NULL", array("user_id"=>$this->user_id));
        if ( count ( $result ) > 0 ){
            return $result[0];
        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

**And I am calling it like so...**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    $_user_id = $_SESSION['admin'][0]['user_id'];
// calls action and determines case
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
    } else if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
    } else {
        $action = 'home';
    }
    $action = strtolower($action);
    switch ($action) {
        case 'home':
            $timeclock = new Timeclock($_user_id);
            $user = new Timeclock($timeclock->user_id);
            $clocked_in = $user->is_user_clocked_in();

            include ('dashboard.php');
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, is it possible to have every function in the class (Once its done) run one after the other and fill in the declared variables at the top (Once I have added them of course) so I can just call the class and have it run through once? Or will I have to call each function individually on demand?

Comment: Is it possible that you can share the database class with us? it seems like the issue here is that your query is failing and that is the problem. Furthermore, you can also add some error reporting by doing, `if(!$result){ echo $this->db->errorInfo(); }` and then exiting or some such thing afterwards. Assuming that `$this->db` is the database handler for your PDO object.

Comment: Okay I added it... Its a rather long class

Comment: `return $this->sQuery->fetchAll($fetchmode);` this is returning null. you need to figure out why that's returning null. sQuery is the executed prepared statement that was created within your Init function. I would start walking backwards from there to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with it to start walking backwards with the script. I really am trying to dig into it though and figure out how it works. On another note, the script above is returning an error that I forgot to mention. It is giving me a **Notice: Array to string conversion ** error on the returned query in the function.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to immediately identify what's going on. If you'd like, you can send me an email (view my profile for the address) and I'll be happy to help you outside of S.O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the attempt to help @Ohgodwhy.  $clocked_in was returning an array because I asked it to select all columns in the table. So when there was a result, it was an array. I changed the return of the function to return true instead of $result[0] because I only need to know if the user is logged in. I could have probably just changed the query to select that column as well. After doing that, it worked great until I provided a value for the table field (Making the user clocked_in). I then got a Undefined offset:0 error because I was trying to call the value of $result[0] when there was no array indexed because the query obviously returns array(0); I just changed the count to check to see if $result exists.

updated code is as follows in case someone comes across this

**Timeclock Class**

```
class Timeclock {
    public $user_id;
    public function __construct($user_id) {
        $this->user_id = $user_id ;
        $this->db = new Db();
        //$this->clocked_in = is_user_clocked_in($user_id);
    }
    public function is_user_clocked_in(){
        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM timeclock WHERE user_id = :user_id AND time_out IS NULL", array("user_id"=>$this->user_id));
        if ( count ($result) > 0 ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```